# Finding vectors in orthogonal complements to create a unique sum

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, linear-transformations, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

Take U,W to be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

$U = \operatorname{Lin}\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c}
-1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
1 \\
1
\end{array}\right)\right\}$

and

$V=\operatorname{Lin}\left\{\left(\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
-2 \\
1
\end{array}\right)\right\}$.

Also : $U \oplus V  = \mathbb{R}^{3}$.

I need to find vectors $u \in U$ and $x \in U^{\perp}$, such that

$\left(\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}\right)$ = $u +x$

That is, find a choice of $u$ and $x$ that is unique and that gives me this vector.

Now, my strategy is to find a orthogonal projection matrix that sends $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ to $U$.

This should give me a vector in $U$ such that when added to a vector $x \in V$, say  $\left(\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
-2 \\
1
\end{array}\right)$ , I can obtain the required vector (in a unique way).

But I if a build a projection matrix P = $U(U^{T}U)^{-1}U^{T}$, and then take $u' = P  \left(\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}\right)$ , where $U = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right]$ ... it doesn't quite give me the vector that I need.

This is is my inital strategy. What am I missing ? What is the right way to approach this ?

Comment: This is an OK approach provided you do the calculations right. I will admit there are faster approaches. For example, the basis vectors together form an orthogonal basis of $\Bbb R^3$, so you get $x\in\Bbb V$ simply by calculating $\left\langle(1,1,0),\frac1{\sqrt6}(1,-2,1)\right\rangle\frac1{\sqrt6}(1,-2,1)$ and then obtain $u$ by finding $(1,1,0)-x$